# Difference between UIsystemfonts

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am newbie learning obj-c. When I typed the following line

```
NSLog(@"System fonts are %@", [UIFont familyNames])
```

I got the following output.

```
Thonburi,
"Snell Roundhand",
"Academy Engraved LET",
Avenir,
"Marker Felt",
"Geeza Pro",
"Arial Rounded MT Bold",
"Trebuchet MS",
Arial,
Marion,
"Gurmukhi MN",
"Malayalam Sangam MN",
"Bradley Hand",
"Kannada Sangam MN",
"Bodoni 72 Oldstyle",
Cochin,
"Sinhala Sangam MN",
"Hiragino Kaku Gothic ProN",
Papyrus,
Verdana,
"Zapf Dingbats",
"Avenir Next Condensed",
Courier,
"Hoefler Text",
Helvetica,
"Euphemia UCAS",
"Hiragino Mincho ProN",
"Bodoni Ornaments",
"Apple Color Emoji",
Optima,
"Gujarati Sangam MN",
"Devanagari Sangam MN",
"Times New Roman",
Kailasa,
"Telugu Sangam MN",
"Heiti SC",
"Apple SD Gothic Neo",
Futura,
"Bodoni 72",
Baskerville,
"Chalkboard SE",
"Heiti TC",
Copperplate,
"Party LET",
"American Typewriter",
Symbol,
"Avenir Next",
Noteworthy,
"Bangla Sangam MN",
Zapfino,
"Tamil Sangam MN",
Chalkduster,
"Arial Hebrew",
Georgia,
"Helvetica Neue",
"Gill Sans",
Palatino,
"Courier New",
"Oriya Sangam MN",
Didot,
"Bodoni 72 Smallcaps"
```

I am just curious to know why there are quotes around font names with multiple words?

```
Thonburi vs "Snell Roundhand"
```

Comment: It's just how NSString's -description method is implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSLog prints `"`-quotes, if it is more than one word, just to make clear, where the string starts and ends. It should be defined in NSArray's description method, as they are only used when printing arrays of strings. <sub>thanks to omz for pointing that out.</sub>

It has nothing to do with the fonts:

```
NSArray *strings = @[@"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", @"gubergren"];
NSLog(@"%@", strings);
NSLog(@"%@", strings[0]);
```

prints

```
2013-03-24 22:18:42.922 stringprinting[22876:303] (
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
    gubergren
)
2013-03-24 22:18:42.923 stringprinting[22876:303] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

If you want to print all names without quotes, you can print each name separately

```
[[UIFont familyNames] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"%@", obj);
}];
```

result

```
Thonburi
Snell Roundhand
Academy Engraved LET
Avenir
Marker Felt
Geeza Pro
Arial Rounded MT Bold
…
```

Comment: No, it's implemented in the `description` method of `NSArray`. Single strings are never automatically surrounded by quotes.